# What is the difference between growing a tree based learning algorithm vertically as compared to horizontally?

Tags: decision-tree, lightgbm

I came across the tree based algorithm Light GBM and I have read that it grows the trees vertically  meaning that the Light GBM grows tree leaf-wise (while some other algorithms grow level-wise). I was just wondering and thinking: What is the advantage of growing a tree vertically? Are there any?

A difference (not necessarily an advantage) which I can see is the way you need to define early-stopping criteria while growing the tree. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this section of LightGBM's documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features.html#leaf-wise-best-first-tree-growth)

[image]

LightGBM uses leaf-wise (or what XGBoost calls [`lossguide`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)) tree growth because it can achieve lower loss (i.e. better fit to the training data) than depth-wise tree growth, holding the number of leaves constant.

In leaf-wise tree growth, the split with the largest gain is chosen, regardless of its level of depth.

> A difference ... I can see is the way you need to define early-stopping criteria while growing the tree

It's true that in this type of tree growth, you now have to consider two closely-related ways to prevent overfitting:

- maximum depth (`max_depth` in LightGBM)
- total allowed number of leaves (`num_leaves` in LightGBM)

I'm assuming this is what you meant by "early-stopping criteria", but wanted to also note that the phrase "early stopping" has a special meaning in GBMs that isn't related to how individual trees are grown. Early stopping, as XGBoost, LightGBM, and other GBM libraries refer to it, means "if performance on held-out data fails to improve for `n` iterations, stop training".